# If a Databricks job takes more than 1 hour, it stops writing to ADLS

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

If a Databricks job takes more than 1 hour, it stops writing to ADLS. 
This is probably because the access token expires.

This means that some large datasets can not be written to disk, because just the writing already takes more than an hour. In other cases, it is possible to finish the writing in one hour, if some computations are done first and only then followed by writing the final output to disk.

Any possible workaround for this will be appriciated

Comment: Try increasing heartbeat interval

Comment: @salim cloud you please eloberate it more? Not able to get you